# Really lost on how to fill allocated memory in C

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, struct, variable-assignment

So for a project I'm doing, I have two files. In the first file, I have a typedef struct, which is a headerfile. In the second, I allocated the memory using malloc(), and then I'm trying to fill that allocated memory with the structure that I have in the first file using the "." operator.

No clue how to do that...

File 1 looks like this:

```
typedef struct
{
     /* members */
}THING;
```

File 2 looks like this (not this is all in main):

```
int *ptr;
ptr = malloc(sizeof(THING)); //allocates memory for THING
```

Comment: Have you been able to open a file?  `ptr = malloc(sizeof(FILE));` seems to indicate you're having trouble doing that... unless, you're defining a new `struct`ure named `FILE`.  You shouldn't as it's already defined in `stdio.h` (I think).

Comment: malloc returns a pointer.  You won't be able to use dot notation to access the members of the `ptr` variable.  You must use arrow notation `->` instead.

Comment: As fiddling bits has pointed out, FILE is already defined in stdio.h.  And you don't need malloc to use it.

Comment: You should clarify whether you try to use the standard library's `FILE` type (as, e.g., in `FILE *fp = fopen("somefile.txt", "r");` , or if you indeed accidentally used that name for an unrelated struct which is yours. If the latter, use a different name.

Comment: Oh my bad, when I put FILE just as something there, I'll rename it. FILE is just there in place of another name.

Comment: Read **much [more about C](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c)** ; BTW, your terminology is wrong, you have two *source files* and technically two [translation units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)). You should share a common `#include`d header file.

Comment: Please provide an [MRE]

Answer (score 2):

```
int *ptr;
ptr = malloc(sizeof(THING));
```

`ptr` is a pointer to `int` but that is not appropriate, as you want to point to the structure `THING`.

The pointer needs to be defined to be a pointer to `THING` -> `THING *ptr`.

> and then I'm trying to fill that allocated memory with the structure that I have in the first file using the "." operator.

I understand what you really mean (to fill the members of the structure with values, not to fill the allocated memory with a structure), but this can´t work as said above `ptr` isn´t an appropriate pointer and `.` isn´t used to access elements via a pointer to an object of the structure. Instead use `->` for this.

Side notes:

1. Always proof if the memory allocation was successful by checking `ptr` for `NULL`.
2. I use `malloc(sizeof(*ptr));`because it ensures that the allocated size is appropriate to the object `ptr` is pointing to.

---

The solution is like:

File1.h:

```
typedef struct s1{
   int a;
   double b;
   char c;
} THING;
```

File2.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "File1.h"     // Note File1.h must be in the same directory as File2.c

int main(void)
{
   THING *ptr = malloc(sizeof(*ptr));
   if(ptr == NULL)
   {
       fprintf(stderr,"Memory could not be allocated!");
       return 1;
   }

   ptr->a = 10;
   ptr->b = 25.4;
   ptr->c = 'A';

   printf("a = %d\n", ptr->a);
   printf("b = %.2f\n", ptr->b);
   printf("c = %c", ptr->c);

   return 0;   
}
```

Output:

```
a = 10
b = 25.40
c = A
```

Comment: Yup, I just named it "THING" instead. This is for an example so the name of it isn't actually FILE.

Comment: @awb0000 Is that what you have asked for or something else?

Answer (score 0):

You have two apparent problems.

First you declared `int *ptr` to point to a memory area allocated for `THING` - that should be a `THING *ptr` instead.

Second you claim to be trying to use `ptr.field` when the syntax for pointers of structures is `ptr->field`.

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
     /* members */
     int thing1;
     float thing2;
}THING;

int main()
{
    THING *ptr;
    ptr = malloc(sizeof(THING)); //allocates memory for THING
    if(NULL == ptr) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        ptr->thing1 = 1;
        ptr->thing2 = 2;
        fprintf(stderr, "one: %d  and two: %f\n", ptr->thing1, ptr->thing2);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Produces:

```
% gcc so.c -o so && ./so
one: 1  and two: 2.000000
```

Answer (score -1):

A file is a stream of bytes. If you want to store data in a file, you need to decide on a file format that is a stream of bytes and then you need to write code to convert data from whatever native format your platform happens to use to that stream of bytes format that you chose for your file.

Don't try to wing it by writing raw structures to a file. That's a much more complex method that should not be attempted until the ordinary serialization methods are mastered.

It's highly advisable to document your file format in as much detail as you can. You can look at documentation for existing file formats to see what such documentation typically looks like.

Or you can just use text with newlines or commas as field separators.